# Significance of open/closed intervals in differentiability definitions

Tags: real-analysis

Definition of f being differentible at a point defines function f in interval (a, b) in my notes. 
Also, for left derivative, function is defined in the interval (a,b] and then for right derivative, [a, b)

It was also similar for defining left hand, right hand continuity.

Is there a reason for defining it like this? Would definition be flawed otherwise?

Comment: If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, how does one define the derivative at $a$ (respectively $b$)? You should be able to see that the right (respectively left) derivative is simple enough to define.

Comment: @user120227 The reason is open intervals are open sets, so you can take two-sided limits. When the domain isn't open, you need to define what happens at the boundary separately due to the two-sided limit not being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be differentiable at point $x\in [a,b]$ if the limit
$$f'(x) := \lim_{y\rightarrow x; \;y\in [a,b]\backslash \{x\}} \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}$$
exists. The function is everywhere differentiable, or differentiable for short, if it is differentiable at all points $x\in[a,b]$.